# Checking Value of max( CASE WHEN ) in a where clause - Edit : HAVING CLAUSE

Tags: mysql, sql, max, case, case-when

I have this query from wordpress table. I'm building an api outside wordpress with other database. I'm tring to get the products *instock* ***only***.

So this - max case when - can give two values, *instock* or *outofstock*.

`max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = "_stock_status" and product_id = pm.post_id THEN  pm.meta_value END ) as product_stock_status`

How can I get only the instock values in this query ?

Full query:

```
SELECT product_id, product_language, product_name, 
max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = "_price" and product_id = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as product_price, 
max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = "_stock_status" and product_id = pm.post_id THEN  pm.meta_value END ) as product_stock_status
FROM search_table
INNER JOIN postmeta pm ON product_id = pm.post_id
WHERE product_language LIKE "en"
GROUP BY product_id
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 15
```

**I hoping to get random products with *product_stock_status* *instock*.**

---

**EDIT: SOLUTION**

> Use a HAVING clause after the GROUP BY i.e. HAVING product_stock_status = 'instock' – Nick

```
SELECT product_id, product_language, product_name, 
max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = "_price" and product_id = pm.post_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) as product_price, 
max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = "_stock_status" and product_id = pm.post_id THEN  pm.meta_value END ) as product_stock_status
FROM search_table
INNER JOIN postmeta pm ON product_id = pm.post_id
WHERE product_language LIKE "en"
GROUP BY product_id
HAVING product_stock_status = 'instock'
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 15
```

Comment: Use a `HAVING` clause after the `GROUP BY` i.e. `HAVING product_stock_status = 'instock'`

Comment: A couple of tips: 1. Always qualify all column names, so `x.product_id, x.product_language... FROM my_table x...` 2. Always include in the GROUP BY all non-aggregated columns in the SELECT. You don't always need them, but it NEVER hurts.